# ¿Cómo puedo cargar los datos en estos select anidados?

Tags: php, select, php5

Realizo un sistema de tickets en el cual al rellenar mi formulario de mi tabla principal **tickets** tengo a *usuarios y áreas* lo que pretendo que haga el formulario en mis **select es que al elegir una area solo me aparezcan los usuarios que pertenecen a esa area**.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

**Estructura tabla tickets (principal)**

```
id                Primaria  int(11)
title                       varchar(100)
process_1                   varchar(100)
process_2                   varchar(100)
category_id       Índice    int(11)
priority_id       Índice    int(11)
turn_id           Índice    int(11)
area_id           Índice    int(11)
status_id         Índice    int(11)
final_id          Índice    int(11)
```

**Estructura tabla area**

```
area_id    Primaria    int(11)
name                   varchar(100)
```

**Estructura tabla final** (usuarios) 
Tengo el campos id_area que pertenece a la tabla area

```
 final_id       Primaria    int(11)
 name                       varchar(100)
 id_area        Índice      int(11)
```

**Código de insertar**

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 /*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
 if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
           $errors[] = "Descripción vacío";
        } 
  
   else if (
   !empty($_POST['title'])
   
  ){


  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $process_1 = $_POST["process_1"];
  $process_2 = $_POST["process_2"];
  $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
  $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
  $turn_id = $_POST["turn_id"];
  $area_id = $_POST["area_id"];
  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
  $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
  $final_id = $_POST["final_id"];
  $kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
  $created_at="NOW()";

  // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql="insert into ticket (title,process_1,process_2,category_id,priority_id,turn_id,area_id,user_id,status_id,final_id,kind_id,created_at) value (\"$title\", \"$process_1\",\"$process_2\",\"$category_id\",$priority_id,$turn_id,$area_id,$user_id,$status_id,$final_id,$kind_id,$created_at)";

  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "Tu ticket ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
    
    
 ?>
```

Código

```html
<?php
  
   $areas =mysqli_query($con, "select * from area order by name");
   $finales =mysqli_query($con, "select * from final order by name");
    
 
?>


  <div> <!-- Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Ticket</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Tickets</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="add" name="add">
                        <div id="result"></div>
      
      
                        
      
      
          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Usuario Final
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="final_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($finales as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['final_id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Area
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="area_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                      <?php foreach($areas as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
                       
      
                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                              <button id="save_data" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

      
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /Modal -->
```

Comment: Para esto vas a necesitar JavaScript (preferiblemente JQuery). Lo que tienes que hacer es rellenar solo el combo de Area y cuando se seleccione una opcion hacer una llamada ajax con el area seleccionada a otro script php que te devuelva los usuarios validos y rellenar el select de usuarios. Aparte de ello tendras que hacer la comprobación antes de insertar pues un usuario avispado puede trampearlo facilmente. Ademas tu sentencia de inserción tiene una grave vulnerabilidad por inyección de SQL.

Answer (score 1):

A mi se me ocurren 2 formas de realizarlo para que no haga falta recargar la pagina en cada selección:

- La manera mas sencilla de hacerlo es cargar todos los usuarios dentro del select, añadirles como `clase` el nombre de la zona y que por defecto mantener todos en `display:none;`. Luego cada vez que el usuario seleccione una zona simplemente hacer `displayblock;` ( *creo que es otro tipo de display el que se le añade a un elemento del select*)

  > Este es un metodo sencillo de crear, pero tambien es el metodo lento a la horade  cargar, es decir si dispones de pocos usuarios esta bien, sin embargo si tienes muchos se cargaran todos todo el rato por lo que puede relentizar bastante.(Yo lo suelo utiliza a veces si se que la cantidad es baja)

En el fichero `form.php`

```
    <select name="areas" id="select-area">
        <?php
            // Hace tu peticion a la base de datos y almacenas ls areas
            $areas;  // Array que contiene las areas

            foreach ($areas as $area ) {
                $area_id = $area["area_id"];
                $name = $area["name"];

                echo "<option value=\"$area_id\">$name</option>";

            }
        ?>
    </select>


    <select name="usuarios" id="select-usuario">
        <?php
            // Hace tu peticion a la base de datos y almacenas los usuarios en un array
            $usuarios;  // Array que contiene los usuarios
            // escribes todos los usuarios
            foreach ($usuarios as $usuario ) {
                $final_id = $usuario["final_id"];
                $name = $usuario["name"];
                $id_area = $usuario["id_area"];
                echo "<option class=\"area-$id_area\"value=\"$final_id\">$name</option>";

            }

        ?>
    </select>
```

En el fichero `form.js`:

> Hace uso de jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-area").change(function(){
        // Obtienes la nueva seleccion
        var areaSeleccionada = $(this).val();

        // Ocultas todos los usuarios
        $("#select-usuario>option").css("display","none");

        // Muestras los usuarios del area seleccionada
        $(".area-"+areaSeleccionada).css("display","block")
    });
});
```

En los estilos, por defecto tiene que estar la siguiente linea:

```
#select-usuario>option{
   display:none;
}
```

- La otra forma es que en el  `select>` de cada zona el `value=" "` sea el ID de cada zona, entonces necesitas preparar 2 bloques de codigo en 2 archivos diferentes:

  `codigo.js`:

  En el javascript utilizando jQuery haces una petición ajax a un fichero preparado para responder a ello con los datos elegidos

  ```
  $.ajax({
      data: { "param": area_id},
      url: "usuariosZona.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      // SI la peticion funciona y devuelve datos:
      success: function (datos) {
          // la variable 'datos' contiene las lineas del select.
          $.each(datos, function (i, usuarios) {
              // Por cada usuarios lo escribes en el select.
          })
      }
  });
  ```

`usuariosZona.php`:

 Recibirá el paramentro que le indiquemos y devolverá los datos en formato JSON

```
<?php
  // Recogera el parametro que le pases
  $id_area = $_POST["param"];  
  // es el archivo en el que tengo mi conexion con la base de datos
  include "../util/conexion.php"; 

  // La query que realizaras en la base de datos
  $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_area=\"$id_area\"";
  // Ejecutas la query, la funcion bdQuery es un creada por mi
  // aunque puedes ejectura la query de la forma que te sea mas facil
  $result = bdQuery($query);

  // devuelves los datos en formato JSON
  echo json_encode($result->fetchAll());
?>
```

Esta seria la forma correcta de paralizarlo si dispones de muchos datos ya que asi no hace falta cargar todo y solo se hará petición de las zonas elegidas.

> Si tenias pensado realizar esto solo con PHP, es posible aunque la pagina se actualizara en cada selección de zona para cargar a los usuarios.

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por tu ayuda, no tengo muchos usuarios y creo que la primera opción funcionaria perfectamente solo que no entendí muy bien tu explicación. Serias tan amable de colocarlo en un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: Añadi tu código muchas gracias por eso, pero aun no funciona como tal ya que si selecciono algún usuario no aparece por defaul el área al que pertenece

Comment: Emmm, en tu pregunta has formulado como mostrar los usuarios al seleccionar una zona y no al reves

Comment: Lo siento si tienes razón,  una disculpa... pero aun no logro selecionar una zona y que me aparezcan los usuarios que pertenecen a la misma

Comment: No puedo hacer una una test de ello ya que no dispongo de todos los datos, sin embargo asegurate de que: <br> 1-jQuery funcion en tu app <br> 2-El html creado con PHP sea el correcot 3-Que almenos la funcion `change()` se ejectua y si lo hace comprueba que los parametros que intenta cambiar el jQuery este correctamente puestos. PD: He modificado el codigo del .js